# How to verify toggle button is enabled or disabled in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I have multiple settings which I need to enabled or disabled in test automation step. I am using python-robot-selenium. I dont want manual to reset requirements before running the script. When my toggle buttons are enabled or disabled the xpath is same for both so I am not able to handle it.
Any other way to achieve it?

Below is the xpath and full xpath for both enabled and disabled status of toggle button

```
Xpath = //*[@id="tabTest"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/label
Full xpath = /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/label
```

Buttons and its inspect element is as below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is worked for me for me to get background color of toggle button. It will helpful to take the action based on **toggle button** **enabled(Green in color)** and **disabled(Grey in color)**.

```
#Check the status of toggle button whether its enabled or disabled.
    ${BG}   Get WebElement     xpath=(//span[@class="slider round"])[3]
    ${bg color}    Call Method    ${BG}    value_of_css_property    background-color
    Run Keyword If    '${bg color}' == 'rgba(204, 204, 204, 1)'
    ...   Click Element     xpath=(//span[@class="slider round"])[3]
    ...   ELSE
    ...   Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in the code is the colour green instead of grey, I would try to add that in the xpath/searchtree because that is the thing that is unique to the status.

Comment: Thanks. I have color for enabled as #C0EB6A and for disabled as #CCCCCC. Now how to get it and compare to click the element if required enabled or disabled. In some condition I need to check if its enabled then need to keep is as is. I tried to get the color by using get element attribute but its not working.

Comment: This one is not working I tried                                                                               ${style}=    Get Element Attribute    xpath=//*[@id="tabtest"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/label/span    background-color
${style}  ${bgcolor}  Split String  ${style}  background-color:
   log  ${style}